# save session for zap

Tags: command-line, zap

how to save the session in OWASP zap using command-line on some location

session persist is possible only through UI?

If I don't save the session file explicitly and close the zap directly, then it doesn't store .session file, to open session next time in zap, I need  .session file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via the API - see [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiGen_core) the documentation, you're looking for `saveSession` operation.

Comment: command i used       "zap.bat -session -h -saveSession C:/Users/exxxriy/Desktop/trying"

Comment: Happy to hear so!